# What are good chess books of 2016?

Tags: theory, books

I'm rated around 1582 blitz on lichess. My rating is much higher in classical ( around 1900). I have a USCF rating but it is still provisional and I don't think it really reflects my skill (also I'm aware lichess ratings are not extremely accurate).

What current chess books would you think would be good to review. I have read through My System and played through some of the games in Fischer's "My 50 Memorable Games". Now I'm looking for modern books that deal directly with variations, not general material.

Of course I could just google "good chess books on" + opening but this leads to a lot of different options and I was hoping someone here might have more insight.

Comment: Your USCF reflects your real skill.  Much more than any of the online ratings which are inflated a lot.  Tournament play is a lot different from online chess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the very best opening book series is [Grandmaster Repertoire](https://www.newinchess.com/Grandmaster_Repertoire-pc-181.html) of Quality Chess. Also [Chess Stars Publishing](http://www.chess-stars.com/book_list.html) is known for publishing high-level opening books.

There is a new chess publisher that looks promising: [Thinkers Publishing](http://www.thinkerspublishing.com/). Currently, they have an opening book on the Richter-Rauzer and this year they'll publish books discussing the Grünfeld, Taimanov and King's Indian.

You can also take a look at the [ChessPub Forum](http://chesspub.com). They have topics on practically every opening line.

Comment: Grandmaster Repertoire is actually published by Quality Chess.

Comment: Oops... You're absolutely right, I corrected my answer. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 5):

> I have read through My System and played through some of the games in
>   Fischer's "My 50 Memorable Games".

I think you need to ask for your money back! My copy of Fischer's book has 60 memorable games ;-)

Seriously, though, Nimzowitsch's My System is regarded as being out of date. I would strongly recommend John Watson's "Secrets of Modern Chess Strategy" which is subtitled more accurately as "Advances since Nimzowitsch". Having read My System you will recognize what he is talking about and after reading this book perhaps begin to understand why you lost some games against stronger players who violated Nimzowitsch's principles but still won.

Some of your bad games will also be due to interfering emotions, bad psychology and misconceptions. Two books by Jonathan Rowson, "The Seven Deadly Chess Sins" and "Chess for Zebras (thinking differently about Black and White)" will help you enormously here.

All 3 of these books are like good films that you can watch several times and get more out of them each time.

Answer (score 1):

The Exchange Sacrifice: A Practical Guide by by Sergey Kasparov

Particularly for advanced chess players.